# How to set default value of ion-datetime element?

Tags: ionic2, datetimepicker

I've set up my datetime picker like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm a" pickerFormat="h mm a" minuteValues="0,15,30,45" [(ngModel)]="whInput"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your var whInput ngModel in your constructor with a string value in the same format,  if you use YY-MM set your var "16-11"
When you use [(ngModel)]="myVar" => this is Two-way binding

see: [enter link description here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel)